# Error when I try to load feed entries in feedjira

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, feedjira

I have error when I try to load feed entries

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
```

I use feedjira 2.0, mongoid
No error when using 1.6.0.

```
  def load_feed_entries
    last_entry = self.feed_entries.last
    if last_entry.nil?
      feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url)
    else
      feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url,
        :if_modified_since => last_entry.published_at.to_time)
    end

    Source.add_entries(feed.entries, self.id)
  end

  def self.update_all_feeds(urls)
    Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(urls,
      :on_success => lambda { |url, feed|
        rss = Source.only(:id).where(:url => url).first
        Source.add_entries(feed.entries, rss.id)
      }
    )
  end
```

Comment: as you seem to use only one function, and as you (we not) probably also know the source code line the error is in, you could probably just read the (API) documentation of feedjira 2.0 and find it there.